# Google analytics for custom data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a small app that have some custom data in the form of:

```
 date value value_type
```

where value_type is old or new. Is there away to send the data to google analytics and have it analyzed there?

I have seen custom events [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) but I couldn't quite figure out how they would work my scenario.

Comment: Do you need this data as a standalone data point, in connection to an event on your site? Or do you need this data in connection to all other collected data in Analytics? (E.g. all sessions, all pageviews within a session?)

Comment: @kgrg more in connection to an event on a standalone data point. I don't have session or so...just a serious of the above mentioned data regardless of who generated it.